# Rails: ActionController::ParameterMissing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I'm building an app that lets :users place :orders at :places. I am defining **orders_params** in PlacesController, but Rails says ParameterMissing ("*params is missing or the value is empty: order*")

How can I fix this, so that one can create an :order for :place_id through **app/place/PLACE_ID/book** ?

**PlacesController:**

```
def book
    @place = Place.find(params[:id])
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save
        flash[:success] = "Success"
        redirect_to @place
    else
        render 'book'
    end
end

private

def place_params
  params.require(:place).permit(:place_name)
end

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:place_id, :user_id)
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
get 'book' => 'places#show#book'
get '/places/:id/book' => 'places#book', as: :place_book
resources :places
```

**OrdersController**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create 
    @place = Place.find(@order.place_id)
    @order = Order.new(user_id: current_user.id, place_id: @place)
    if @order.save
        flash[:success] = "Order placed"
        redirect_to @place
    else
        render 'book'
    end
end

def show
end

def edit 
end

def update
end

def destroy
end

private

def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:place_id, :user_id)
end
```

end

**Model: Order.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_one :place
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :place_id, presence: true
## OTHER VALIDATIONS
```

**View: app/views/places/book**

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
    <!-- SOME FORM_FORS -->
    <%= f.submit "Place order", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You have not defined any routes for `orders` ?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace and relevant server log in the question?

Comment: @dkp get 'orders/new' and resources :orders

Comment: `<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>` - This points to `OrdersController`. can you show that ?

Comment: @dkp just did, below Routes.rb

Comment: In `OrdersController`, under create method you have `@place = Place.find(@order.place_id)` - Do you have `@order` available to you ? Also, add you complete form.